# Is there a bug in Chrome 122.0.6261.70 (and Chromium browsers) for the position fixed grid children?

Tags: css, css-position

Does anyone know if there is any recent change in Chrome version 122.0.6261.70 (and other Chromium browsers) generating this weird behaviour in the position fixed grid children?

As far as I know (and I think it was behaving this way a few weeks ago), when you set a position fixed to an element, it is removed from the normal document flow, so if I have a grid child and I set a position fixed to it, it should be removed from the grid container and therefore, not being affected for its constraints. This is how the grid children are behaving in all the browsers and devices except for the new versions of the Chromium ones (Chrome, Edge...).

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-content: flex-end;
  height: 100svh;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-child {
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.info {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  max-height: 55svh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.fixed {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.fixed:has(:checked) {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0 0 auto;
}
.fixed p {
  max-width: 70svw;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-wrap: balance;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <label class="grid-child fixed">
    <input type=checkbox />
    <span>position: fixed</span>
    <p>I should occupy the whole width when the input is checked</p>
  </label>
  <div class="grid-child info">
    <p>Why Android Chrome Browsers (only) are being affected for the CSS property below, when the element position is set to fixed?</p>
    <pre>
.grid-child {
  justify-self: center
}</pre>
    <p>It shouldn't be affected for the grid constraints, since it is removed from the grid container once its position is set to fixed, and therefore it should take all the window width instead of being justified to the center</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I attach here some pictures from a Chrome browsers before and after version 122 so you can see the different behaviour:

Desktop:

| position: static |
| --- |
| [image: Windows: grid child position static] |

| position: fixed |  |
| --- | --- |
| Right: before Chrome 122 | Wrong: after Chrome: 122 |
| [image: Windows: grid child position fixed - Right] | [image: Windows: grid child position fixed - Wrong] |

Mobile:

| position: static |
| --- |
| [image: Android: grid child position static] |

| position: fixed |  |
| --- | --- |
| Right: before Chrome 122 | Wrong: after Chrome: 122 |
| [image: Android: grid child position fixed - Right] | [image: Android: grid child position fixed - Wrong] |

Comment: It doesn't occupy the whole width when the input is checked on Edge/Windows10 so can you describe exactly what is different on Android?

Comment: @AHaworth You are right. It is happening also in Edge. So should we consider it a desired behaviour then or should we report it so they can fix it?

Comment: I've just checed an it is a change added to the new Chrome version 122.0.6261.70. 
I think this is not an expected behaviour when an element has a position set to fixed since according to MDN "it is removed from the normal document flow". 
I've just reported the problem since it could be affecting several websites (it was affecting mine).